# How to package all faces of a font into one family file (Mac)

Tags: fonts, software-recommendation, font-management

I've got a few fonts I've purchased over the past few years.

These are decent quality fonts with, on average, 8–15 different faces for the family.

The problem I have is each face is listed separately in various applications (Photoshop, Indesign, etc.) Rather than simply one item with a submenu for faces.

For example I have:
(fig. A)

```
FontA Bold >
           Regular
FontA Bold Italic >
           Regular
FontA Italic >
           Regular
FontA Regular >
           Regular
```

Rather than:
(fig. B)

```
FontA >
        Bold
        Bold Italic
        Italic
        Regular
```

What tool on the Macintosh can combine these faces so they are all listed under the family name? As in the figure B, above.

I know there are a couple of high-end apps (Fontographer, FontLab). Are there any basic smaller apps to simply edit the font info without editing character and other tables? I don't want to edit the actual font data specifically, merely the titles and naming structure I believe.

How do I do this with the tool suggested, specific steps please?

**Notes:**
Running Mac OS 10.7, but can boot to 10.6 or 10.8 if needed. I am not absolutely looking for freeware. If there's a paid app to do this, I'm fine with that. If someone wants to outline steps in FontLab or Fontographer, I'm all ears.

These are commercial .otf fonts.

Comment: Sounds like you want to make it into `.dfont` format. If you wanted to undo this (I know that is not the case in this question) you would use the DfontSplitter found here: http://peter.upfold.org.uk/projects/dfontsplitter

Comment: No, not a .dfont (I hate those). I simply want each face to properly reference the same family. Everything works as is, but rather than 1 menu item with the family name, then a sub menu for all the faces, I have 1 menu item for each face even though they are the same family.

Comment: Would any of the fonts you've purchased even allow you to do this by their EULAs? I guess I'm wondering if you can do this without editing the font "software" itself.

Comment: I don't care about the EULA - I'm editing for my use, not sharing and distributing. And I'm not looking to edit character tables. I merely want all faces to index the same family. I get no response from Myfonts where the fonts were purchased.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

RoboFont is a great software (mac only) for font editing on so many levels. It also does what you're looking for: allows you to open individual files and edit their font info and then resave in whatever format you need. I recently had to do exactly what you're asking with my copy of Gotham which was installing as individual files and not as a family.

http://robofont.com/

The purchase price on RoboFont is pretty steep, but really, the software is aimed at people who are drawing and editing their own fonts.  For this purpose, the 15-day free trial may be all you need.  Who knows, maybe you'll get hooked and buy a license. :)

**Steps for changing Font Family**

1. Open your .otf files in robofont. They'll appear in separate windows.
2. For each window, click on the tab Font Info (3rd tab from the left in the toolbar). It'll slidedown an editor with a few more tabs.
3. The first tab is **General** which includes an input box for Family Name. The 2nd tab is **OpenType** which allows you direct access to the nameTable so you can edit all of that info including style names.
4. Once you edit the info, simply type Command(⌘) G or choose **File... -> Generate Font**. Ensure it's exporting as .otf and save to desired location

RoboFont is also built beautifully in python, so you can execute your own custom scripts if you need.

Comment: Looks interesting. Priced around the same as FontLab Studio or Fontographer. Can you provide steps?

Comment: FYI if you just need this for a one-off font family renaming, just download the 15 day free trial -- should be plenty of time to rename your files without throwing down 400 euros.

Comment: Yup. Marking this as correct because of the 15 day trial. This allows for renaming without any cost essentially. You should add the steps to the answer itself.

Comment: I don't understand, OP asked how to merge two of the same fonts (that have different weights) into one file. Your detailed instructions seem to be how to convert OTF to TTF...

Comment: I agree with @TheMuffinMan . This answer looks like an ad.

Answer (score 12):

I just combined the Nexa fonts into one Font Family on my my Macbook Pro running OSX 10.8 (Mountain Lion).  The UI looks old (and not retina), but it worked.

```
$ brew install fontforge --with-x
$ brew linkapps
$ fontforge
```

## Edit the Font

1. Open the file and goto Element > Font Info.
2. Under PS Names, change the Font Family to the common name you want.  Leave Fontname and Name For Humans alone.
3. Under TTF Names you can change the String for String ID "Styles (SubFamily)" to a unique name for that specific font like "Book-Italic"
4. Select "Preferred Family" and click the delete button.
5. Select "Preferred Style" and click the delete button.
6. Click OK

## Save the File

1. Select File > Generate Fonts
2. Change The select box under the font name to OpenType (CFF)
3. Click Save
4. Ignore Errors and Save

## Test

Close out of Font Book and then open the file and it should have the common font name in the title and the unique name in the drop-down.

Thanks to user568458 for their great answer.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not able to test this on a Mac, and the Windows version is too flakey and crash-prone to test, but this should work:

- Install [FontForge](https://fontforge.github.io) (open source font editor)
- Load up the fonts which aren't falling into the same group.

  - An example free font that doesn't fully group for experimentation is [Aller](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Aller), where Aller Light/Light Italic and Aller Display don't group with Aller regular/bold/italic. Aller is a quite nice smooth friendly sans, but beware the hideous 'Display' variant, which will burn your eyes.
  - Best to work on files that aren't installed and aren't in use... (I remember experiencing a lot of crashes the few times I foolishly tried working on the installed files in system folders...)
- [`Element > Font Info`:](http://fontforge.org/fontinfo.html)

  - You want to change Family Name so that all variants have the same family name (in Aller example, Aller Light and and Aller Light Italic have family name Aller Light, change this to Aller).
  - Make sure that 'Weight' says something meaningful that doesn't clash with your existing fonts (e.g. Aller Light has weight 'Book', change to 'Light').
  - You may find you also need to change Fontname, but that should be unnecessary.
- Check anything else you want to tweak, then when ready, [`File > Generate Font`](http://fontforge.org/filemenu.html#Generate). Create an appropriate font file, install it. It should merge in lists with the others with the same Family Name.

---

If this doesn't work, some possibilities to investigate:

- I seem to remember seeing somewhere once that on a Mac there's a `fonts.list` file that is a bit like a cache of fonts and file mappings. You might need to be manually update this in some cases to make the system aware of changes you've made - but I think it normally handles it automatically.
- You can try grouping your .TTF font files into one [.TTC collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType#TrueType_Collection) file, by opening them all at once and using [`File > Generate TTC...`](http://fontforge.org/filemenu.html#GenerateTTC),  then choosing the appropriate files in the dialog. Again, this should be unnecessary (but might make housekeeping easier to have one file).
- You can try Merging fonts together into one, using [`Element > Merge`](http://fontforge.org/elementmenu.html#Merge), selecting the font files to be merged in. This should be unnecessary, however.

---

Quick note - I don't know very much about how FontForge works under the hood, but I believe it has quite a lot of interaction with a remote server. No problem for genuine legitimate work like this, but anyone tempted by the fact that in theory copyrighted fonts can be imported and editted using FontForge should double-check their FAQ first: http://fontforge.org/faq.html#legal.

And a quick note on "simply edit the font info without editing character and other tables" - I'm no expert, but my understanding is that since font files are compiled binaries rather than markup, then, a bit like with a .swf, any change (even a simple change like tweaking the font name) requires you to de-compile the file into markup you or the software can work with, then re-compile it, generating new binary after making your changes. This is a process that always can introduce noise and unexpected changes, as no de-compiler is ever perfect - and that's just a feature of editing anything that isn't the original source file. It should work so long as care is taken and so long as the font files are reasonably conventional.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to investigate but I don't think Font Forge will work. I'm running Mac OS 10.7 (can use anything from 10.6 to 10.8). FontForge appears to only support up to OS 10.5. I'm guessing it's built on PPC libraries, which are not part of OS 10.7. By the way these are commercial OTF fonts, not .ttf files.

Comment: @Scott Would have been useful info in the first version of the question! But it shouldn't be a problem, [fontforge does support otf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FontForge#Supported_formats) and can be installed on Lion, [skip to the end of this article](http://joewong.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/how-to-install-fontforge-on-mac-os-x.html) or see second comment below the article for a detailed (if unintentionally patronising...) step by step. FontForge is a handy powerful tool to have, and surprisingly well documented. If the OTF is edit protected, it's probably not possible (not legally, anyway...)

Comment: (re. that last point about edit protection - I'm sure I remember reading somewhere that it's possible to lock certain features of a font file to prevent their being editted by legitimate means. I can't find any resource on it, however, in the context of fontforge, OTF, or TTF, so I think I might have mis-remembered it or confused it with something else)

Comment: Quick note on FontForge - it's considered to be equal in features to the $650 FontLab (some say it has more), and inconvenient install and ugly UI seem the main downsides. If you're not creating or editing fonts every week, it's a great way to simply add a powerful font tool to your belt. Comparison article: http://ilovetypography.com/2007/10/22/so-you-want-to-create-a-font-part-1/ If you plan to create or edit fonts regularly, then something slicker like **Fontlab** will be a good investment. Steps for this task will be very similar: `Import` OTF, edit same lines in `Font Info`, `Export` OTF.

Comment: Workign on it. Finally got Homebrew installed. This article was helpful with that - http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/ ignore step 1 in the link you posted, but step 2 is good. I've got FF running and can edit the family name.. but I'm having issues generating files.

Comment: While all this has been helpful, if for no other reason to show me the direction I do not want to go, I've found an easier solution. However it does cost a bit of money. I appreciate your posting and which I could upvote you 50 times. Unfortunately, after several hours of effort this does not solve the problem in a usable fashion. While I have FF running and could edit or create a font, it does not allow me to generate proper files for .otf PS files only .otf TT files seem to be supported on the Mac. In addition, FF throws up all kinds of errors which my solution does not.

Comment: @Scott Open source stuff does often have stability issues. If this put you in the right direction and helped you find a better option, how about posting your solution as the accepted answer, and giving this the bounty for helping you find the right approach?

Comment: Yup. I'll wrap things up in just a bit. :) no worries.

Comment: My solution isn't as great as it first appeared. I thought Font Lab's Type Tool would do this. It LOOKS like it will, but they've **purposely** built in a limitation for preventing the renaming of otf families (which isn't listed anywhere on their site and doesn't throw errors in the app either - it's a feature which simply appears to work but does not) and they require FontLabStuio or Fontographer for otf family renaming. Still considering if this is worth $400-$600 to me.

Comment: @Scott wow, I hate it when vendors cripple their own software like that. There will be some small software out there somewhere that does this... (the only other two candidates I know of are Windows only, [Typograph](http://www.neuber.com/typograph/) and [Font Creator](http://www.high-logic.com/font-editor/fontcreator.html) ). There's **one potential alternate approach**, which is hacking that Mac font cache list thing. Quick google finds [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA39011?vie..) - sounds hacky, but it's an official Apple source from Feb 2012, so should be legit.

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't really answer OP's question (which was about `.otf` files), but I figured I'd provide some instruction on merging `.ttf` files together, since it might get you on the right track for other font formats.

If you want to bundle a bunch of `.ttf` files together, you need to generate a `.ttc`. You can do this easily in FontForge.

### Download FontForge

Go to the [FontForge website](http://fontforge.github.io/) and follow the instructions to download and install the software.

### Gather your `.ttf` files

I'm using RedHat's [Liberation Mono](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Liberation-Mono) as an example. It is a "well behaved" font, meaning that everything is named properly. If it isn't, look at Chad's answer which talks about going into the "Element > Font Info" in FontForge to cleanup the names.

### Open all the `.ttf` files you want to combine

Under the "File" menu, select "Open"
[image: File->Open]

Navigate to the `.ttf` files, shift + click to select them all and hit "OK" to open. 
[image: Select all .ttf to open]

### Generate the `.ttc`

Now you will see all the glyphs of the fonts you just opened. From any of these windows, click "File -> Generate TTC...".

[image: File->Generate TTC...]

In this dialog, simply select all the fonts you want to combine. I unselected the "Untitled1" project, which was the default project when I opened the program. Click "Generate" after that.

[image: Select faces, click Generate]

### Confirm proper generation

If you did everything right, you should have a single `.ttc` file that bundles all your `.ttf` font face styles together. You can check this in your favorite font program, like FontBook (on macOS).

[image: Double check in FontBook]

### Congratulations

I'm no font expert by any means, so I don't know what other packaging options you have, if you didn't want to use `.ttf` or `.ttc` files. It was good enough for what I needed.

And to save others some trouble, I also figured out that the "Element -> Merge Fonts..." dialog, while it sounds like it does what you want, simply merges the glyphs of two fonts together. This only is useful if one font is missing some glyphs that you want to fill in from a different font. As far as I can tell, you cannot assign multiple glyphs to a code-point (which is what styling is; different representations of the same character). However, I could be mistaken!

Answer (score 1):

For a while I have been looking for a similar solution and always got back to this thread. I've found something that solved the problem for me and though it would be good to share for further reference.

The Fontlab's TransType app, does exactly this, and a bit more:
http://new.fontlab.com/font-converter/transtype/

Comment: Wow, this is an excellent reference. TransType is *precisely* what I was looking for, coming to this question (and it's a hell of a lot more pleasant to use than installing FontForge and trying to puzzle through it on a Retina display :P).

Answer (score -3):

I would look into some of the font management software titles, such as FontExplorer X Pro or Extensis Suitcase Fusion:

http://download.cnet.com/FontExplorer-X-Pro/3000-2316_4-10906718.html?tag=dropDownForm;productListing;pop

Comment: Font Management applications do not reconfigure internal font data. My question is not about font management. It's about editing a font package. I have a font manager (Font Agent Pro) which I've used for years. And I've tried Suitcase (yuck) and Font Xplorer, none of these applications allow for altering internal family references in a file.