# Font Organisation

Tags: fonts, font-management

I am trying to organise my fonts so when I am in Illustrator or PS that the fonts are as one single font.

**Not** one font for bold, one for italic etc. - Like this:

[image]

Rather it should be in sub-divisions, like this:

[image]

For example there are some fonts you install that install as a singular font. So when I scroll looking at fonts it takes an eternity to get through them all as some have so many different variants or weights.

But I need to just click on [desired font] and then choose the variant as when I am scrolling through fonts, it takes forever just to move past one font as sometimes they have 20-30 variants not installed as a group/family.

Comment: There are tons of font organizing apps out there and which one you use is really a matter of personal preference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to link font styles in Windows?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35874/how-to-link-font-styles-in-windows)

Comment: @Vincent.. UK vs US spelling :) It just looks wrong to me.

Comment: @Scott I understand. Policy is to leave the post in the original writer's spelling, hence my rollback.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on if the font file is created as one file with several variations or the variations are spread over several files. If it's the last alternative you would have to repack the font files into one single file, if you'd want them to show as a group in Ill. or PS. I recommend getting a font manager app and use it to browse fonts. Only install the fonts you want to use. Don't install a lot of fonts... it just leaves long lists and a big mess like you're experiencing now. I recommend AMP Font Viewer, it's a bit old but it works best for me. Fast and free.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I was looking at Fusion but didnt like it much and doesnt work properly. So I will look at what you suggested.

How do I repackage a font into one single file? I dont mind spending the time to do that.

Comment: I don't know, try googling 'font creator software' or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Much of this has to do with *how the font is constructed* and it is not directly user-editable.

When some designers or foundries create fonts, they create a separate font for each face and don't bother to add a *common family name* to the actual font files. This causes they "family" to not be seen in applications. It's *lazy* font construction with no attention to common details from an end user's perspective.

There's not a great deal you can do to alter this other than directly edit the font files themselves in order to *add* a common family name where it's lacking.

See Here: [How to package all faces of a font into one family file (Mac)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10535/how-to-package-all-faces-of-a-font-into-one-family-file-mac)