# How to generate one font file consisting of multiple font weights (i.e. multiple font files)?

Tags: fonts, typography, web-fonts, font-management

I have multiple font files, each of a different weight. The problem arises when they are used in, applications and Wordpress. For example, they appear like this:

```
  [family]         [weight]
 - sailec-light   - regular
 - sailec-regular - regular
 - sailec-medium  - regular
 - sailec-bold    - regular
```

Because of this, every time I switch between these weights I always have to click the dropdown that's the Font Family, and never the Font Weight, because all four exists in the Font Family section, leaving the Font Weight section completely unused and always pointing to "regular". This makes my font family list messy, and

I would like to have them be one single file (i.e. one font family). Like this:

```
  [family]  [weight]
 - sailec   - light
            - regular
            - medium
            - bold
```

I already tried RoboFont to combine them by changing the family names and style names but haven't been successful because RoboFont opens each .otf file in a separate window, and I don't know how to generate one single font file that is the combination of all four.

The problem with this is that in Wordpress I can only upload one font family to be the body font. So if the font file that I upload is **regular** doesn't include **bold**, then I will never be able to use bold in my body text.
[image: Wordpress font upload]

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: ".. one single file (i.e. one font family) .." is not the usual state either. These fonts are badly constructed - the internal style data is messed up. Check if your supplier has an updated version, and if not, request this to be fixed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to link font styles in Windows?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35874/how-to-link-font-styles-in-windows) or http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10535/how-to-package-all-faces-of-a-font-into-one-family-file-mac

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to package all faces of a font into one family file (Mac)](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10535/how-to-package-all-faces-of-a-font-into-one-family-file-mac)

Comment: I read @Scott 's [article](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10535/how-to-package-all-faces-of-a-font-into-one-family-file-mac) on packaging all faces of a font into one family file but the RoboFont solution from the first answer didn't work for me. I couldn't comment there because I didn't have enough rep points.

Scott, did you end up using RoboFont and did it work for you? If so, what did you write in the nameTable? I am stuck at the [2nd and 3rd steps](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10535/how-to-package-all-faces-of-a-font-into-one-family-file-mac).

Comment: Actually, I resolved myself to the fact I needed FontLab or Fontorapher to do this well (didn't try TypeTool due to OpenType limitations) and it was ultimately cost prohibitive to worry about it. So I either deal with a different family for each face, or I use a different (better constructed) font.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Scott. Have you actually tried FontLab or Fontographer, or is it an idea? I'm still interested in merging them because I don't think the [purchasable fonts](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typedynamic/sailec/) are better constructed - they're also in the same fragmented form (1 weight per file).

Comment: I tried a trial of Fontographer (the cheaper of the two) and it worked.. . But given the time and learning curve involved, for me it was easier just to change fonts, even if that meant purchasing a different font that was constructed as a single family.  I also learned when purchasing fonts, to ensure they are constructed as a single family rather than separate files.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the family names of all the files to match in FontForge.